# Compress a file and access through all mobile platform?

Tags: mobile, compression, cross-platform

You know using Winrar you can compress files in windows and extract it in Unix!
likewise is there any compression format available in mobile to compress and access it to all mobile platform's.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zlib](http://zlib.net/) is a fairly ubiquitous compression library. When you say "cross-platform" and "mobile", I'm thinking, first and foremost, iOS and Android. A little searching reveals that zlib exists in various forms for both programming frameworks.

Since you have control of the program in a mobile environment, you are also free to adapt compression algorithms that yield superior compression (either general purpose compressors or compressors that work best for a particular type of data). But for a quick proof of concept, you should be able to compress data on a PC using zlib and send it to iOS or Android for decompression with included libraries.

Comment: thank you i will check out what it is and also i need to compress some files in a mobile and it should be accessed with all the mobile platform's .. can you suggest me any solution

Comment: Any zlib port should be able to compress as well as decompress data. I expect that to be true for the iOS and Android ports.